# I don't understand web parsing completely

Tags: python, html, html-parsing

I tried using this code below to extract hyperlinks, and it worked for 1 website I tried it with:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time


def timedelay(amount):
    print("...")
    time.sleep(1)
    amount -= 1


url = input("Enter website of which you wish to parse all links from: ")

website = requests.get(url)

data = BeautifulSoup(website.text, 'html.parser')

web_links = data.select('a')

actual_web_links = [web_link['href'] for web_link in web_links]

fixedLinks = set(actual_web_links)

print("There!")
time.sleep(1)

for link in fixedLinks:
    print(link)
```

Unfortunately, sometimes the output gives some extra characters and not just the links.

The website that I am using is :

stores.aceedventure.com/collections/textbooks-year-10

When I try to run the code with this website, the output has characters that aren't just the links.

This is the output:

```
Enter website of which you wish to parse all links from: https://stores.aceedventure.com/collections/textbooks-year-10
There!
/collections/textbooks-year-5/Dwi-Emas
/collections/textbooks-year-2
/pages/contact-us
/collections/school-books
/collections/textbooks-year-1/Sri-Emas
https://stores.aceedventure.com/pages/seller-profile-1?sophie-sews
/collections/textbooks-year-10/products/igcse-biology-workbook-ebook-new-2022
/collections/golf-academy-products
/collections/textbooks-year-10/products/complete-economics-for-cambridge-igcse-o-level-3re
/collections/textbooks-year-10?view=view-24&grid_list
/collections/textbooks-year-3/Dwi-Emas
/collections/fashion
https://stores.aceedventure.com/pages/seller-profile-1?callums_closet
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ToyZW-SmLpVHHYNM_vmW8G_ylNEV0BuM/view?usp=drive_link
/collections/mit-stem-international-school
/collections/uniforms
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kY6GxPY3jVQDRI_6bwoQ_PBy8CWgCOQt/view?usp=drive_link
https://stores.aceedventure.com/pages/seller-profile-1?buildlab
https://stores.aceedventure.com/pages/seller-profile-1?jacktus
/collections/art-c
/collections/books
/collections/textbooks-year-6/MIT-STEM
/collections/dwi-emas/Dwi-Emas
/collections/textbooks-year-10/IKS-42+QKS-41
https://www.instagram.com/stores.aceedventure/
/collections/edventurewitherica
https://shopify.com/22501753/account?locale=en
/collections/textbooks-year-9/IKS-41
/collections/textbooks-year-2/Sri-Emas
/collections/uniforms/Sri-Emas
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S-D_MHUjD5PGrcQiczK8v86qzDZpXq_B/view?usp=drive_link
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EkTuyuIcShBqILGhx0sjaL8q6wYtm24A/view?usp=drive_link
/collections/textbooks-year-10/Dwi-Emas
/collections/ace-valentine-collection
/collections/textbooks-year-10/products/1-click-ordering-school-books
/collections/textbooks-year-10/Sri-Emas
/collections/textbooks-year-11
/collections/textbooks-year-11/Sri-Emas
https://stores.aceedventure.com/collections/uniforms/MIT-STEM
/collections/puro-coffee
/collections/textbooks-year-8/Sri-Emas
/collections/textbooks-year-10/products/cambridge-igcse-and-ol-additional-mathematics-coursebook-2re
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cUcFS_bU-f9Nj_J3P4t6Do8Y6EUsPfOx/view?usp=drive_link
/collections/textbooks-year-8/KS-32
/collections/chemcaper
/pages/shipping-and-returns
https://sriemas.edu.my/
https://stores.aceedventure.com/pages/seller-profile-1?momoyo
/collections/textbooks-year-9/MIT-STEM
/collections/textbooks-year-2/Dwi-Emas
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fom6YE9P9em0kpmUso-dufonh9yNDPO0/view?usp=drive_link
/collections/textbooks-year-3
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1w_uv-Fb2Xa9oG0zjaIxi1WGB6hU4oqh6/view?usp=drive_link
https://www.facebook.com/profile.php?id=100093056268216
/collections/textbooks-year-9/Sri-Emas
/collections/sri-emas/Sri-Emas
/collections/textbooks-year-10?view=view-36&grid_list
/collections/textbooks-year-11/IKS-43+QKS--42
https://drive.google.com/file/d/151Lt5u-RgqTpdM_50_4-4frqivaWNU3R/view?usp=drive_link
/collections/arts-crafts
/collections/brands-1
/collections/textbooks-year-5/Sri-Emas
#site-header-nav
/cart
/collections/textbooks-year-10?view=view-48&grid_list
https://stores.aceedventure.com/pages/seller-profile-1?z3hern-space
https://stores.aceedventure.com/pages/seller-profile-1?fae_self_care
/collections/textbooks-year-10/products/think-mathematics-secondary-textbook-3a-3b-print-digital-pack-8th-ed-1
/collections/mthemovement-x-dwi-emas/mthemovement
/collections/vendors?q=The%20Bookstore
/collections/textbooks-year-10/products/cambridge-igcse-mandarin-chinese-students-book-2e-chinse-b-new-2022
/collections/textbooks-year-7/Dwi-Emas
/collections/ace-biosphere
/collections/textbooks-year-10/products/igcse-physics-workbook-ebook-new-2022
/collections/aevdc
/pages/faq
/collections/textbooks-year-10/products/cambridge-igcse-enterprise-coursebook
https://www.shopify.com?utm_campaign=poweredby&utm_medium=shopify&utm_source=onlinestore
/collections
/collections/textbooks-year-10/MIT-STEM
/collections/lil-unicorn
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HHkgd0GN0J0j9rO5RDfAbhCk-me7nUVo/view?usp=drive_link
/collections/textbooks-year-10/products/cambridge-igcse-and-o-level-additional-mathematics-coursebook-with-digital-version-2-years-access-3e-new
/
/pages/privacy-policy
/collections/textbooks-year-10/products/cambridge-igcse-chinese-as-a-second-language-coursebook-chinese-intermediate-new-2022
/collections/primary-sri-emas
/blogs/news
#
/collections/textbooks-year-10/products/igcse-physics-student-book-ebook-new-2022
/pages/about-us-1
/collections/textbooks-year-10/products/new-syllabus-maths-textbook-3-7e
/collections/textbooks-year-6
/collections/textbooks-year-10/products/jauhari-textbook-4a
/collections/electronics
/collections/textbooks-year-5
/collections/school-books/stationery-&-exercise-books+DWI-EMAS
/collections/textbooks-year-4/Dwi-Emas
/collections/textbooks-year-6/Dwi-Emas
/collections/textbooks-year-7/KS-31
/collections/workshops-events
/collections/vendors?q=Ace%20Ed-Venture%20Market%20Store
/search
/collections/textbooks-year-9/Dwi-Emas
https://stores.aceedventure.com/collections/educational
https://stores.aceedventure.com/pages/seller-profile-1?takoyaki-crochet
/collections/byjus
https://stores.aceedventure.com/pages/seller-profile-1?shailaja_grace_guillory
/collections/textbooks-year-10/products/cambridge-igcse-and-o-level-accounting
/collections/textbooks-year-8/Dwi-Emas
https://stores.aceedventure.com/pages/seller-profile-1?zuperdwi
/collections/textbooks-year-1/Dwi-Emas
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cPr2InN2dkhLvx9HE63j4wJqsmeX2dth/view?usp=drive_link
https://dwiemas.edu.my/
/collections/textbooks-year-11/MIT-STEM
/collections/textbooks-year-4/Sri-Emas
#site-main
/collections/textbooks-year-7/MIT-STEM
/collections/textbooks-year-6/Sri-Emas
/collections/textbooks-year-10/products/igcse-chemistry-workbook-ebook-new-2022
/collections/primarydwi
/collections/uniforms/Dwi-Emas
https://stores.aceedventure.com/pages/seller-profile-1?craftiviti
/collections/textbooks-year-4
/collections/school-books/stationery-&-exercise-books+MIT-STEM
/collections/textbooks-year-8/MIT-STEM
/collections/ace-edventure-merchandise-1
/collections/uniforms/MITstem
/collections/secondarydwi
https://stores.aceedventure.com/pages/seller-profile-1?glitter-up-with-k
/pages/terms-and-conditions
https://sp-seller.webkul.com/?sid=6448
/collections/textbooks-year-10/products/igcse-biology-student-book-ebook-new-2022
/collections/textbooks-year-1
https://stores.aceedventure.com/pages/seller-profile-1?scrap-n-crop
/collections/textbooks-year-10/products/igcse-chemistry-student-book-ebook-new-2022
/collections/textbooks-year-7/Sri-Emas
https://stores.aceedventure.com/pages/seller-profile-1?home-essentials
/collections/secondarysrii-emas
/collections/school-books/stationery-&-exercise-books+SRI-EMAS
/collections/textbooks-year-3/Sri-Emas

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Why are there lines like the collections that aren't actual links?

Comment: The href attribute of an html "a" tag might not always be a link.  It also might not only be a link.  It would help if you provided the website that is giving you the issue.

Comment: The website I am using is my friend's school's store, https://stores.aceedventure.com/collections/textbooks-year-10

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `data.select('a')` to `data.find_all('a')` for better consistency and clarity.

And use `web_link.get('href')` instead of `web_link['href']` to handle cases where the 'href' attribute might be missing.

And change

```py
fixedLinks = set(actual_web_links)
```

to

```py
fixedLinks = set(filter(None, actual_web_links))
```

to remove any None values from the list of links.